# css3: apply styles based on how elements are positioned

Tags: css

I have an styling issue and I was wondering if this could be solved using pure css (HTML is a given!). Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="a">aaaaa</div>
<div class="b">.....</div>
<div class="a">bbbbb</div>
<div class="a">ccccc</div>
<div class="a">ddddd</div>
<div class="b">.....</div>
```

Now I need a `border-bottom` on elements which have a class `a` ONLY if that element is not followed by an element with a class `a`. Is this possible?

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7p9hj/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no "previous-sibling" selector (I think there might be something coming in CSS4 until then...).

This is a dirty filthy hack and I'm not proud of it but it certainly works in your example:

```
.a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.a + .a {
    border-top: 1px solid #FFF; /* set this to your background colour */
    margin-top: -1px; /* shift this element up 1px to hide the previous elements border */
}
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7p9hj/2/)

Comment: Nice solution!! Here is a [link](http://www.webmonkey.com/2011/10/discover-whats-new-in-css-4/) which explains how to style the parent when the selector targets its child.